# Parse a remote xml.gz file of a database without downloading

Tags: python, bash, pubchem

I need to parse a Pubchem database to search for certain clues on the pages of compounds

(Toxicity codes, to be exact, they look like 'H300'), and then add their CIDs to the correspondent lists

The Database is here
https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pubchem/Compound/CURRENT-Full/XML/

But the  xml.gz files there are so big that they can't be unpacked on my computer
So maybe there is a way to read this files directly on the server of a PubChem

Comment: testing one of the files .... a 1 GB *gz file uncompressed to ~18 GB; if you plan to run multiple 'searches' against a given file you may want to consider downloading the (eg, 1 GB) *gz file and then run your local unpack-in-memory + search operations; main objective is to limit yourself to downloading the *gz file once while still making use of local cpu+memory to run repetitive unpack+search operations; then again, if you plan on doing this type of operation on a regular basis then you may want to look at adding some (relatively cheap) disk space to your system ...

Comment: keep in mind that `parse ... without downloading` means running an operation on the remote host ... something most (if not all) websites are not going to allow so, you will need to *download* the (compressed) gz file; the next question is ... how many times will you need to download the same file, or do you have room to download the file *once* and then run your multiple unpack+search operations locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I would approach this is to use `curl` and `gunzip` and maybe `grep`:

Example:

```
curl -ks https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pubchem/Compound/CURRENT-Full/XML/Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz -o - | gunzip | grep someString
```

This will stream down the file, and in realtime decompress it, which will allow you in realtime to grep for what you need

Comment: and, importantly, without having to store the data compressed or uncompressed anywhere.  however whether this is going to work for you depends on the processing you need to do to the file.  and `grep` may not actually work for xml, since it cna e structured all sorts of different ways you may have to actually parse the XML.

Comment: Yep, `grep` was just my addition to the example just to show the point